# How can I get a MAC address using Javascript on Windows and Linux?

Tags: javascript, mac-address

How can I get the MAC address of a PC using Javascript?

It *should* work on Windows and Linux.

I think it should look like this:

```
macs.getMacAddress();
            var macadd = document.macaddressapplet.getMacAddress();
```

Comment: If you're looking to accomplish this with normal JavaScript from within any standard web browser, and without asking the user to install additional plugins, etc., to support this - sorry, not possible.

Comment: @ziesemer 's carefully worded comment is correct. JavaScript is designed to work only within the "sandbox" that is the web browser. Anything more than that requires an API that the user must agree to install

Comment: BTW... great question!

Comment: Are you looking for the MAC Address of the web client or the HTTP server?